# Regex expression for everything but a float value

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a custom DocumentFilter for a JTextField, in such a way it only allows users to enter float values. This means:

- 0 to 9 characters
- a '.' character
- possible to also enter '-' and '+' at the beginning

I wrote one for just everything but integers, and my regex was just `\D+`. But now the thig is more complicated.

I think the expression for a float with this characteristics would be `[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+`, but using just `\D` instead of `\d` doesn't work here, since I am able to put more than one decimal point, +/- are not allowed...

This is how my code looks like:

```
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class OnlyFloatDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("[-+]?(\\D*[.])?\\D+", ""), attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("[-+]?(\\D*[.])?\\D+", ""), attr);
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: A quick googling: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=float

Comment: "The `\D` metacharacter is used to find a non-digit character."

Comment: Oh, I figured from the title that he wants `Regex expression for everything but a float value`

Comment: Does this mean that the string cannot even *contain* a float value or just that the whole string should not be a float value?

Comment: I don't think your approach will work.  It looks like you're trying to "replace everything that isn't a float" with "", but a simple regex with `replaceAll` isn't going to do that for anything but the very simplest cases (such as an integer where you can just eliminate all the non-digits).  If the string can contain more than one float, you'll need a loop using `Matcher.find()` with a regex that represents a float.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You can't "filter out" a float from a string that can not be parsed into a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ANSWER

First you find all floats in your string, you then would remove them all starting at the last float found.  The reason you start from the end of the string and work to the beginning is because this stops the issue of the string changing and thereby the index and length becoming an issue.

So use the below RegEx to find all `floats` then simply use string.remove with their indexes from the last found to the first.

Enjoy

---

### REGEX [DEMO](http://www.regex101.com/r/nL5jZ3)

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0hEq_Sz9j5qZXht3)

---

### DESCRIPTION

```
/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/gi
        ^ Start of string
    Char class [-+] 0 to 1 times [greedy] matches:
        -+ One of the following characters -+
    Char class [0-9] 0 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
        0-9 A character range between Literal 0 and Literal 9 \. 0 to 1 times [greedy] Literal .
    Char class [0-9] 1 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
        0-9 A character range between Literal 0 and Literal 9
    $ End of string
```

---

### ALTERNATIVE REGEX

```
^[-+]?([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)$
```

This regex would match a number with a `.` at the end without any other numbers.

**Examples**

```
+1.
-2.
2.
6.3
2323356.342478986756
.5
```

Comment: `\b` isn't needed before `$`.

Comment: `55.` isn't a float, it is a number with a `.` but you could easily change the regex if you disagree. removes \b

Comment: The alternative regex won't match `.55`

Comment: @sln fixed.  It won't match `.` if you bring that up i don't know what to tell you other than why?

Comment: You can reduce it to `[-+]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)`

Comment: @sln That's just your answer.  You can absolutely do what you are saying, as it works for all edge cases.  But I don't steal other peoples answers...

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String removeAllNonFloats(String input){
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[-+]?(?:\\d*[.])?\\d+").matcher(input);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(matcher.find()){
        sb.append(matcher.group(0));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that if you give it something like `"a=1.3, b=22.5, c=3.14159"`, the result will be `"1.322.53.14159"` which is probably not useful.  Maybe appending a blank space in your loop would work.  But the real answer depends on what the questioner really wants to do with the floats.  The logic definitely needs to look something like this.

Comment: This will only match '`-4`' in '`-4.`'

Comment: @sln Yes, because `float.Parse("-4.");` throws a `FormatException`.

Comment: `float fTest = float.Parse("-4."); Console.WriteLine(fTest);` Output `-4`, A string with numbers followed by just a dot never has, nor ever will be an illeagal format in a string to float conversion in any language.

Comment: @sln I'm pretty sure I tried it and it produced an exception;=. I tried it again now and it worked. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

To find a valid float without the exponent, you would have to take into account the
four possible forms:

```
 \d
 \d .
 \d . \d
    . \d
```

This can't be done without some kind of alternation.
IMO, the best way is a regex like this:

```
 # [-+]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)

 [-+]? 
 (?:
      \d+ \.? \d* 
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
```

And set your boundry conditions to whatever you need.